# {Netbeans}The form file does not contain valid XML.Form cannot be opened.Contents is not allowed in prolog

Tags: netbeans

I was recently working on a really huge project in netbeans. I saved it in my desktop, and then proceeded to save it also in my USB. However, the next day, when I learned it could be for a later date, I deleted the one in my USB.When I put on the one in my desktop, all the work I had done was not saved on it, including the making of new JFrames etc. So I used a program to recover my deleted files. I now have loaded them into the netbeans IDE< however, there is an error sign next to most of them. When I click on a class inside my project with the error,an error message comes up before I can access it. It says "The form file does not contain valid XML.Form cannot be opened.Contents is not allowed in prolog." When I press "OK", my class has "coding" which looks like:

```
W�'6��G��ԧ��(g&�Cd�nw|7�\ej��
�;���كG�s=�Bl+��6�r�@ma���'�f�T�9Kx�q�M�G�t�q� �:���� \!�%İ��P�&!�[�R���`�,+��U���"���Ј���yF&mÛ�
�
Y   ?/,8��@�t:�ԇ
��lOѪ|T�^?v"
```

....that.

And when I go to "design view" that message comes up again. What should I do? What CAN I do? I really need the bulk of my project to finish it in time!!!Oh, the project is for tommorow, so the quicker answer the better :'(

Comment: I have seen this happen when Netbeans' corresponding .form and .java files get out of sync, which seems to just glitch out from time to time. Viewing the source code of the .form file may reveal multiple XML declarations something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` twice, as did for me. Removing the extra line may not always work though..

Comment: it is wise to keep a back up of your project just in case....mine did the same for me today and i replaced it with a backup of the project and worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the history of the file and copy the content of .form file then go to directory and open the 0byte file .form by the editor and paste the content! I have done this and it worked for me.

Comment: I actually gave up IT as a subject so it didn't matter anymore hehe :D I really found it interesting but the teacher was really mean to me.

Comment: But I still am grateful for your comment although I installed netbeans like  a year ago :D My grade head forced me to drop IT cos I had too many subjects to boot ^_^

Answer (score 1):

right click on the latest file from History ->revert (the .form)